# wmware compile cpp file linux

Tags: c++, linux

I've installed wmware player on my pc (I have windows vista 32 bit). The virtual machine that I need to use is has linux. I've set the shared folder and I go to it with my virtual machine.
The problem is that linux doesn't compile my cpp file. I write:

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

and nothing happen.
I don't know why. The only error given is when I start the virtual machine, it says:

```
Binary translation is incompatible with long mode on this platform. Long mode will
be disabled in this virtual environment. Applications requiring long mode will not
function properly as a result. See http://vmware.com/info?id=152 for more details.
```

Comment: Tried to copy file into vm and then to compile?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run a 64-bit VM on a machine that doesn't support 64-bit. Which makes sense, since 32-bit Windows isn't a suitable host for a 64-bit VM - although technically it would be possible to create such a system, it's full of messy situations that are much easier to deal with if the host system has at least as many bits as the VM.

You either need to get a VM that is a 32-bit install, or upgrade your windows to 64-bit (assuming you have a 64-bit capable processor, of course!)

Comment: Is there a way to set VM to 32-bit?

Comment: Well, not really. If you have a VM image, then it's got an installed OS inside it that is either 32- or 64-bit, and if it's a 64-bit OS, then it won't boot on a 32-bit VMWare install.

Comment: What do you get if you do `uname -a` and `file 'which gcc'`? (the ' around `which gcc` should be backquotes, but it won't allow me to write those)

Comment: uname -a give me:Linux hpc 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: 'which gcc' gives me: gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation termined

Comment: So that is a 32-bit version of Linux. Should be no problem with that. 

You then need to type `file` followed by the path to `gcc`, so the output of the command `which gcc`. If you type `some-command 'another-command'` and the quotes around another command are back quotes, it will pass the output of the `another-command` to `some-command` - which is a very handy way to do things that require long/complicated output from one command as input to another.

Comment: I typed: file 'which gcc' but it doesn't work again. After typing file 'which gcc' I recieve the message: simbolic link to gcc... but if I type: 'which gcc' I get a fatal error

Comment: Well, `which gcc` with backquotes around it, without anything else will run gcc, so that's entirely what you'd expect. However, if it's symbolic link you will need to find the actual file - what I'm trying to find out is what actual executable is. However, I'm slightly confused, as you have a 32-bit Linux, it shouldn't be able to (or want to, need to, however you want to express it) run anything in 64-bit mode.